# Auth0 return status code 400 after on subsequent polls for request token

Tags: go, httprequest, auth0

I am attempting to perform Device Authorization Flow on a CLI in Go. I have followed the steps in https://auth0.com/blog/securing-a-python-cli-application-with-auth0/ to set up my application in Auth0. After successfully requesting a device code, I attempt to get a request token.

```
// Gets a request token.
func (loginJob *LoginJob) GetRequestToken(deviceCodeData loginResponse.LResponse) error {
    //Setup an http request to retreive a request token.
    url := loginJob.Domain + "/oauth/token"
    method := "POST"
    payload := strings.NewReader("grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Adevice_code&device_code=" +
        deviceCodeData.DeviceCode + "&client_id=" + loginJob.ClientID)

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, reqErr := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)
    if reqErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(reqErr)
        return reqErr
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    authenticate := false
    for !authenticate {
        authenticate = PollRequestTokenStatus(req, client)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(deviceCodeData.Interval) * time.Second)
    }
    return nil
}

func PollRequestTokenStatus(req *http.Request, client *http.Client) bool {
    res, resErr := client.Do(req)
    if resErr != nil {
        log.Panic(resErr)
        return true
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, ReadAllErr := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if ReadAllErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(ReadAllErr)
        return true
    }
    fmt.Println("res.Body: ")
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    if res.StatusCode == 200 {
        fmt.Println("Authenticated!")
        fmt.Println("- Id Token: ")
        return true
    } else if res.StatusCode == 400 {
        fmt.Println("res.StatusCode: ")
        fmt.Print(res.StatusCode)
        return false
    } else {
        fmt.Println("res.StatusCode: ")
        fmt.Print(res.StatusCode)
    }
    return false
}
```

The idea is that I poll Auth0 for a request token at specific intervals. The first time I poll, I get a 403 Forbidden:

```
{"error":"authorization_pending","error_description":"User has yet to authorize device code."}
```

However, on subsequent polls, I get 400 Bad Request:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unsure why this is happening. I have tried manually polling Auth0 with Postman, and I have always managed to avoid error 400 using Postman.
[image: Manually polling Auth0 with Postman]
How do I fix this problem?

Update: It turns out for some reason Go will reset all the request headers whenever it calls *http.Client.Do(), so I tried moving the request construction inside the for loop. Now my code looks like this:

```
// Gets a request token.
func (loginJob *LoginJob) GetRequestToken(deviceCodeData loginResponse.LResponse) error {
    // Setup an http request to retreive a request token.
    url := loginJob.Domain + "/oauth/token"
    method := "POST"
    payload := strings.NewReader("grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Adevice_code&device_code=" +
        deviceCodeData.DeviceCode + "&client_id=" + loginJob.ClientID)
    authenticate := false
    var pollErr error
    for !authenticate {
        authenticate, pollErr = loginJob.PollRequestTokenStatus(url, method, payload, deviceCodeData)
        if pollErr != nil {
            log.Panic(pollErr)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(deviceCodeData.Interval) * time.Second)
    }
    return nil
}

func (loginJob *LoginJob) PollRequestTokenStatus(url string, method string, payload *strings.Reader, deviceCodeData loginResponse.LResponse) (bool, error) {
// Setup an http request to retreive a request token.
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }
    req, reqErr := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)
    if reqErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(reqErr)
        return false, reqErr
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    res, resErr := client.Do(req)
    if resErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(resErr)
        return false, resErr
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("res.StatusCode:")
    fmt.Println(res.StatusCode)
    if res.StatusCode == 200 {
        fmt.Println("Authenticated!")
        fmt.Println("- Id Token: ")
        return true, nil
    } else if res.StatusCode == 400 {
        return true, nil
    }
    return false, nil
}
```

I have a different issue now. Instead of returning error 400 on subsequent polls, I am getting 401 instead:

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I need to instantiate strings.Reader from within the for loop. My code is now as follows.

```
// Gets a request token.
func (loginJob *LoginJob) GetRequestToken() error {
    url := loginJob.Domain + "/oauth/token"
    method := "POST"
    authenticate := false
    var pollErr error
    //Keep polling Auth0 for a request token until status 200 or until invalid grant
    for !authenticate {
        authenticate, pollErr = loginJob.PollRequestTokenStatus(url, method)
        if pollErr != nil {
            log.Panic(pollErr)
        }
        //Sleep for the interval duration in the device code data. If we poll too fast, Auth0 will give 429 status.
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(loginJob.DeviceCodeData.Interval) * time.Second)
    }
    return nil
}

func (loginJob *LoginJob) PollRequestTokenStatus(url string, method string) (bool, error) {
    //Construct a new Reader. This must be done within this function, or else Go will read to the end of the REader and not
    //properly construct our http request.
    payload := strings.NewReader("grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Adevice_code&device_code=" +
        loginJob.DeviceCodeData.DeviceCode + "&client_id=" + loginJob.ClientID)

    //Create a new http Client. This is done within this function because Go will not erase previous Client settings if we
    //pass a client instance as a parameter, which will mess up our post request.
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }
    //Construct a new http request. This must be done within this function because Go will nuke the request headers after every
    //call of &http.Client.Do().
    req, reqErr := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)
    if reqErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(reqErr)
        return false, reqErr
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    res, resErr := client.Do(req)
    if resErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(resErr)
        return false, resErr
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println("res.StatusCode:")
    fmt.Println(res.StatusCode)
    if res.StatusCode == 200 {
        fmt.Println("Authenticated!")
        fmt.Println("- Id Token: ")
        return true, nil
    } else if res.StatusCode == 400 {
        return true, nil
    }
    return false, nil
}
```